# does it have meaning using flask(or elasticsearch) and nodejs webserver together?

Tags: python, node.js, elasticsearch, flask, rest

I have question of structure in API communication

I have Frontend server , Python web server which in running on flask and elasticsearch webserver
and all of them are runnging on same ip but different port

I have curiosity of how I would have to make structure between Frontend and Backend

Now I am thinking of taking structure like this

```
frontend -> nodejs -> backend(python, elasticsearch)
```

but when I think that python flask and elaticsearch could be web server themselves

I think this sturcture would also have no problem at all

```
frontend ->  backend(python, elasticsearch)
```

which sturcture would I have to take?
What advantage would be made when I put nodejs between frontend server and backend server

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Any answer to your question will depend on the use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer

**Flask + Nodejs?**
no need.Only code complexity rises.
Client can directly request to Flask Web Server. there is no problem

**ElasticSearch(Database) + Nodejs ?**
need to do it although Nosql provides restful api. because of security purpose. If Database Address is exposed to clients, the Database can be ruined by behaviors like inserting worthless records or even worse removing all indexes in it. So middleware like nodejs or flask should be positioned between client and database

So my new structure would look like this

```
Client -> flask Web server -> ElasticSearch
```

or

```
Client -> flask web server
Client -> nodejs -> ElasticSearch
```